# Cannot update my own comment using YouTube Data API and Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, youtube, youtube-data-api, scopes

I'm working with Google Apps Script and Google Sheets for update the comments I made on certain videos.

While using the code I post bellow, I got this message:

> The comment could not be updated due to insufficient permissions. The
> request might not be properly authorized.

Despite the fact I'm updating my own comment from my Google/YouTube account and I've set the authorization scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl` - as indicated on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/update#auth).

I also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69579026/12511801) - which is similar to mine - but, mine is oriented to Google Sheets.

This is the code I'm using:

```
// Text from the comment_ID "": 
/* The Magic Cylinder animation is real or am edit?
 * Honest question, I don't play MD, just looking video edits xD 
 */

/** 
 * Comment (reply) to send as body request. 
 * Sample body  - took from YouTube Data API documentation: 
*/
var myCommentBodyRequest = {
  "id": "UgyBzIHN1fFHveTCRb14AaABAg", // <= Id of my comment.
  "snippet": {
    "textOriginal": "The Magic Cylinder animation is real or an edit?" // <= Updated comment text.
  }
};

// Update the comment: 
/** Response of the updated comment:  */
var commentCreatedResponse = YouTube.Comments.update(myCommentBodyRequest, "snippet");

// Testing results: 
Logger.log(commentCreatedResponse);

// Update the cell with the new text:  
sheet.getRange("E" + sheet.getCurrentCell().getRow()).setValue(commentText);

// Show alert: 
ui.alert("The comment was updated successfully.");
```

I already have the "`appsscript.json`" file updated as follows:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Bogota",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "YouTube",
        "version": "v3",
        "serviceId": "youtube"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"
  ]
}
```

Normally, when a scope is added and/or Google Scripts shows an alert indication that Google Sheets requires permission, I accept the permission, but, I keep getting this message.

I think this error I'm getting is because the script must be authorized/approved by Google, but, I haven't found any evidence

Is there any missing steps/configurations to update the comment using Google Sheets?

Added tickets on Issue Tracker:

- [#247150284 - Google Apps Script](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247150284)
- [#247521476 - YouTube Data API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247521476)

Comment: Can you remove `oauthScopes` key and value and run the script?

Comment: @TheMaster, yes and the same error shows: `The comment could not be updated due to insufficient permissions. The request might not be properly authorized.`

Comment: @TheMaster I also tried with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube`, but, the same result/error shows.

Comment: Remove authorization in https://myaccount.google.com/permissions , remove oauthscopes fully, and click Run. When the  request page shows up, note the scopes requested in url, authorize and run it

Comment: @TheMaster same results, unfortunately.

Comment: I guess you're better off creating a issue in the tracker.  Something the old tracker link says, that is to be [noted](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203111370#comment2): *Also, please notice that you won't be able to update a comment unless you have a private YouTube Channel or are logged in with your Brand Account.*

Comment: @TheMaster done. This is the [ticket I made](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247150284) - let's hope more people vote for this ticket and get more attention from the Google Team.

Comment: Adding a answer may help people to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved internally by the YouTube team.

[Link of the response to the ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247521476#comment9):

> Verified by el...@google.com.
>
> Hello, This issue is already fixed.
> Please let us know or open this ticket, if you still encounter this
> issue. Thank you.

Since then, I tried to replicate the issue and even to this day (*14/12/2022*), I can update my own comments via YouTube Data API and Google Apps Script.